# jquery ajax cpu high usage

Tags: php, jquery

dI am using this ajax.php to get livenews auto update.
but sometimes it causes high cup usage, sometimes (120%)
it is running on a apache.
can you please inform me with this issue:
the code is:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://domaine.com');
preg_match("/<ul[^>]*id=\"toautoupdate\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/ul>/si", $data, $match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Comment: preg_match can be heavy depending on input length and REG EXP you're using. Is it really the only solution ? What are you trying to do with your preg_match ?

Comment: preg_match is used to search and get the news from a specific category

Comment: You want to match `<ul ...>... id="toautoupdate"...</ul>` and echo everything in the `<ul>` element, right ?

Comment: <script>
  (function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
      $("#toautoupdate").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: 'dark-thin',
    scrollButtons: {enable: true}
   });
         });
  if ($("#toautoupdate").length) {
   $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
   });
   setInterval(function() {
    $.get('/ajax.php', function (data) {
     if ($(data).length && data != $("#toautoupdate").html()) {
      $("#toautoupdate").html(data);
      $("#toautoupdate").mCustomScrollbar({
       theme: 'dark-thin',
       scrollButtons: {enable: true}
      });
     }
    });
   }, 60000);
  }
 })(jQuery);
</script>

Comment: it is the jquery used in the html of the module

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: If you've time to learn a DOM parser, the best solution would be this one otherwise : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php